# What is Firefox - Smart cache size?

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

There is an option in about:config (Firefox 4):
`browser.cache.disk.smart_size.enabled`

I have tried to enable and disable this option, nothing changes. The cache just grows, and grows.
What's the point?

(Couldn't find any detail about this.)

Comment: Well, I have left it enabled (True), and set the disk.capacity to 1GB. Just a moment ago, I have cleaned the cache. It was over 800mb. (Why won't firefox throw out the unused stuff?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sets the disk cache size according to the available disk space. If you have a fairly modern computer, there should be at least 1GB available.

Comment: In fact, I think the cache size should not be more than 10MB; I even set my cache in Opera as zero (0) to use only the ramdisk. This saves the HDD and if you have an SSD is even recommended.